# Authorization as other user from oracle db in spring

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So, I have three users in my oracle database: user_role, admin_role, provider_role. They have access to execute different procedures. Also, I have a Spring boot app with a login page. How can I change my connection to the database according to the database role?

Comment: I think you are rubbing up against the fact that Spring Boot makes common setup simple, but doesn't make everything simple. Default position is that you define one data source in your yaml/properties and Spring Boot manages the connection pool, integration with whatever persistence framework you are using etc behind the scenes. In your case you need connections made by multiple users, so you *probably* have to manage multiple connection pools yourself. I'm not 100% sure that there isn't a spring boot built in solution but I haven't come across one

Answer (score 0):

In your data model, you should introduce a concept called permissions and roles. A role can hold multiple different permissions.  You don't need three different tables like user_role, admin_roles, and provider_role. Just create a single table for users, another tables for roles and permissions. For every user there will be at least one role and each role can hold multiple permissions.

Your SpringBoot application should have an authorization layer. All the execution path should goes through this authorization layer. All your model(DB) layer access, constrained with the permissions allowed for different type of users.  That gate keeping task is going to be taken care by your authorization layer in your service.